# I need to update a file with my generic style based on redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a file with all my generic styles (styles.js), like primary color, secondary color, shade of gray and other stuff.

When the user logs in, I have his primary and secondary color in my redux state.

What I want: When this props in my redux state update I need that my styles.js heard to this change and update all the places that reference this primary and secondary color.

I've done this and doesn't work. It seems like the styles.js never update.

my styles.js:

```
import store from 'store';

//here I check if my primaryColor is undifined, if it is, I set the default colors. (The app is always with this deafult color, but if I check my redux state the colors is being updated)
const pColor = !store.getState().login.data.primaryColor ? '#386B38' : store.getState().login.data.primaryColor;
const sColor = !store.getState().login.data.secondaryColor ? '#666' : store.getState().login.data.secondaryColor;

export default {
  white: '#FFF',
  lighter: '#EEE',
  light: '#DDD',
  regular: '#999',
  dark: '#666',
  darker: '#333',
  black: '#000',

  primary: pColor, //these are the props to be updates
  secondary: sColor, 
  success: '#9DCA83',
  danger: '#E37A7A',


  transparent: 'transparent',
  darkTransparent: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
  whiteTransparent: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
};
```

Login component e.g:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View } from 'react-native';

import styles from 'stylesLogin'; //this is my specific style to use in login

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.pColorView} />
      <View style={styles.sColorView} />
    );
  }
}
```

stylesLogin.js

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { colors } from 'styles'; //this is my generic styles, where I have my primary and secondary color

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pColorView:{
    backgroundColor: colors.primaryColor,
  },
  sColorView:{
    backgroundColor: colors.secondaryColor,
  }
});

export default styles;
```

Comment: Please show us at least some of your work in order for us to help you better

Comment: @RexLow please check if it's better now. Thanks!

Comment: As it stands, your component only ever receives the state once, that's why it won't update. Instead, you should try `withStyles` or `connect` your component before export. Check out `react-redux` bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should make state in the reducer such as `state.styles` and set the `initialState` to it as your *default styles* as described

```
const initialState = {
    primary: // primary default,
    secondary: // secondary default,
}
```

bind them in the reducer and update them.

With the help of redux helper function [`connect()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), make a **store aware HOC** and bind the styles directly to the `props`

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'


class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        const {pColor, sColor} = this.props
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: pColor}} />
            <View style={{backgroundColor: sColor}} />
    );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state = ({
    pColor: state.styles.primary,
    sColor: state.styles.secondary
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Login)
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you tried shouldn’t work.

As I can see you want to update primary and secondary inside styles.js

Try this
First import styles from ‘styles.js’ in your actions file

Then
Inside your actions when user login is successful make the changes like this

styles.primary = ‘red’ //anycolor
styles.secondar = ‘blue’

If you can’t see the changes then try navigating as your component needs to refresh to fresh import changed style.

Comment: I did this way, but the changes do not reflect in all my application.